# How to enable import from .ts files without extension?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

When opening a Svelte project with TypeScript all imports from `.ts` files give `Cannot resolve symbol`

[image]

The errors disappears if the `.ts` extension is added, but I don't think this can be the solution?
When removing the import the IDE will also *'auto add'* it again without the extension.

Js files are created alongside the .ts files *'excluded from compilation'* in case that's important
[image]

Which configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, tracked at [WEB-57711](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57711/Svelte-module-import-from-ts-file-is-not-resolved-if-there-is-same-named-svelte-file-in-the-same-folder).

Unfortunately the only workaround for now is using different names for `.ts` and `.svelte` files located in the same directory